# SQL SERVER: OPTION(MAXRECURSION n) not working with dynamic variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

Techies,
This more or less works when the date range is between 1/1/-1/3.  I have 2 problems I need to solve. The first is that SQL Server will not let me do this: OPTION (MAXRECURSION @recdays). The next, I am pulling results for 1/4, when I only want results up to 1/3. Any advice for getting this to work? I tried turning the query into something I could run through EXEC sp_executesql. Then I had a new problem--I couldn't write out to #StoreXJoinDate since that spawns another session. If I convert to ##StoreXJoinDate I can't kill it from the outer session because that session doesn't own it.

```
--DEBUG
declare @beginDate date
declare @endDate date 

set @beginDate = cast('1/1/2021' as date)
set @endDate = cast('1/3/2021' as date)

declare @recdays int

select @recdays = datediff(day,@beginDate,@endDate)

;WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT
        [GenGapDate] =  @beginDate
        UNION ALL SELECT
         [GenGapDate] =  dateadd(day,1,[GenGapDate]) 
        FROM
         Dates
        WHERE
         GenGapDate <= @endDate 
  ) SELECT
   d.[GenGapDate],
   s.StoreNumber
   --s.OpenDate,
   --s.ClosedDate
  -- into #StoreXJoinDate -- drop table #StoreXJoinDate
  FROM
    Dates  as d
     cross join Dimension.Stores s
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 3)
```

Here are the insert statements to build Dimension.Stores

```
 create table Dimension.Stores
  (StoreNumber int);

 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (1);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (5);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (7);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (8);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (9);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (10);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (11);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (12);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (13);
 Insert into Dimension.Stores (StoreNumber) values (14);
```

Comment: Using a variable `MAXRECURSION` is, at the very least, a very unusual way of doing it, and at the very worst a terribly inefficient way of doing it if the recursion gets large. Why not simply generate a numbers table (for which there are multiple approaches, including (non-dynamic) recursive CTEs) and then use that to generate dates?

Comment: Why not get rid of the recursion and use a tally? They're way faster than an rCTE and (like I hinted) isn't recursive so can't suffer the problems

Comment: The plan in the broader sproc this is an excerpt from, is to wrap a custom message around  @recdays that would set the recursion cap to a reasonable limit (<=10000). I see this direct cross ref approach as an alternative to a numbers table.

Comment: I realize unfettered recursion is never a good approach, however, the intent is to limit the recursion.

Comment: *"however, the intent is to limit the recursion. "* So why not remove it completely?

Comment: I limit it because the default is 100. That's not enough if the range is over a few weeks. There is a very limited number of store test data added here. MAXRECURSION allows for a specified cap. It's limit is 32,000--which is more than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use that recursive CTE to load Date table.  Like this:

```
drop table if exists Dates
Create Table Dates([Date] date primary key)

declare @beginDate date
declare @endDate date 

set @beginDate = cast('1/1/2010' as date)
set @endDate = cast('12/31/2099' as date)

declare @recdays int

select @recdays = datediff(day,@beginDate,@endDate);
WITH GenDates AS (
        SELECT
        [GenGapDate] =  @beginDate
        UNION ALL SELECT
         [GenGapDate] =  dateadd(day,1,[GenGapDate]) 
        FROM
         GenDates
        WHERE
         GenGapDate <= @endDate 
  ) 
Insert into Dates([Date])
Select [GenGapDate]
from GenDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then to cross-join a date range with another table, run a query like:

```
select *
from Stores s
cross join Dates d
where d.Date between '20200101' and '20200220'
```

or the equivalent

```
select *
from Stores s
join Dates d
on d.Date between '20200101' and '20200220'
```

If each store has a different window, then use APPLY  eg

```
select *
from Stores s
cross apply
 (
   select [Date] 
   from Dates d
   where d.[Date] between s.BeginDate and e.EndDate
 ) d
```

Comment: Hmmm... that gives me dates from 1.1.2010 onward.  It's really the store numbers attached (cross referenced) to a limited date range that I am trying to capture for later use.

Comment: Right, but now any time you need a date range to use in a CROSS JOIN you can just query the Date table.  Having a calendar table is also useful for other purposes, as you can store Year, FiscalYear, DayOfWeek, IsHoliday, etc.

Comment: OK, let's say I use this date table--so I go to it. Now I want a subset of it recursed by stores that don't have a date attached to them. So I want to see 1/1/2021 10, 1/2/2021 10, 1/3/2021 10, etc. How do I make this happen?

Comment: Just remove the cte and replace the reference to it in the actual query with the Date table  and then filter for the period desired. As just updated :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than limiting the recursion, simply get rid of it, then recursion isn't a problem. Plus, a Tally is way faster than an rCTE anyway:

```sql
DECLARE @beginDate date;
DECLARE @endDate date;

SET @BeginDate = cast('20210101' as date);
SET @EndDate = cast('20210301' as date);

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @BeginDate, @EndDate) + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @BeginDate) AS D
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT D
FROM Dates;
```

If you need more than 1,000 days, just cross join to `N` more in `Tally`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.